# Generating a Unique Id for each Iframe, or building an Iframe out of DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to set a unique Id for each Iframe so they render correctly. I have a renderId variable that increments. I'm trying to append that to the Iframe Id.

```
document.getElementById('iframe-test' + renderId);
```

Entire code block here:

```
let renderId = 0;
   const render = post => {
   renderId++;
   const node = document.createElement('div');
   node.innerHTML = `
     <h2 class="centered">
       <a href="${post.link}">
         <br>
             <iframe id="iframe-test" width="100%" min-height="100%" src="">
             </iframe>
         <br>
         ${post.title} 
         </a>
         <br><br>
         </h2>`;
         app.appendChild(node); 
         document.getElementById('iframe-test' + renderId);
```

No videos are showing. I've tried changing the quotes on this line:

```
  <iframe id="iframe-test" width="100%" min-height="100%" src="">
```

I need some extra steps before this line, but I'm not sure what.

```
  document.getElementById('iframe-test' + renderId);
```

Full app: http://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/BWROeW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building the iframe out of DOM nodes. This way I could build a easily repeating iframe without having to generate a unique ID for each frame. This doesn't actually generate an ID as per the original question, but it does allow you to copy an Iframe div with no unique ID issues. I amended the title of the question to reflect this broader solution.

HTML:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

JS:

```
const app = document.querySelector('#app');
const render = post => {
 const node = document.createElement('div');  
   node.innerHTML= `${post.title}`;
  node.className= 'clip-title';
    app.appendChild(node);

var a = document.createElement('iframe');
a.className = "clip-content"
a.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + strippedURL; //add your iframe path here
a.width = "100%";
a.height = "100%";
a.padding = "500px";
app.style.textAlign = "center";
document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

`'<iframe id="iframe-test"'+renderId.toString()+' width="100%" min-height="100%" src="">'`                                                                       EDIT: You just forgot to give a different Id to each div. You was looking for an id that was not assigned so I added the `renderId.toString`. Maybe it will work without toString. Not sure

Comment: Thanks. I will try that this week.

Answer (score 1):

Create your 'unique' id in a variable at the top of the function:

```
let renderId = 0;
const render = post => {
    renderId++;
    const iframeId = `iframe-test-${renderId}`;
    const node = document.createElement('div');
    node.innerHTML = `<h2 class="centered">
                        <a href="${post.link}"><br>
                          <iframe id="iframe-test" width="100%" min-height="100%" src="">
                          </iframe>
                          <br>${post.title} 
                        </a>
                        <br><br>
                      </h2>`;
    app.appendChild(node);
    document.getElementById(iframeId);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the YouTube reference as the id like this:

```
// post.link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmIo702wjm4)

const uniqueId = `iframe-test-${post.link.substr(post.link.lastIndexOf('v=') +2)}`;

// iframe-test-TmIo702wjm4
```

Comment: Trying that right now. It definitely logs a unique ID. I'll update if I get a complete answer...

Comment: @RubyRube Cool. Let me know if you need anything else!